# static property inheritance CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

Let's define this simple code :

```
class Foo
  @foo = 'blah'
  console.log(@foo)

class Bar extends Foo
  constructor: () ->
    console.log(@foo)

  bar: () ->
    console.log(@foo)

b = new Bar
b.bar()
```

And result is :

```
blah
undefined
undefined
```

How can I access `@foo` in inherited class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually want to write

```
console.log(@constructor.foo)
```

in `Bar`'s constructor. (Working example [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20Foo%0A%20%20%40foo%20%3D%20%27blah%27%0A%20%20console.log%28%40foo%29%0A%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28%40constructor.foo%29%0A%0Anew%20Bar).) `@constructor` points to the class (`Bar`), which inherits the static properties of `Foo`. Those properties aren't on the instance, which is what `@` points to from the constructor.

(Yes, it's weird that it's `@constructor` rather than `@class`, but that's because `obj.constructor` is a JavaScript-ism, not a special CoffeeScript syntax.)

To clarify further: In the class body, `@` points to the class. In the constructor, `@` points to the instance. Hence the apparent inconsistency. I devote a lot of time to this in the chapter on classes in my book, *[CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript)*.

Comment: And if I want to access to @foo from another method than the constructor ?

Comment: I've modified my question to reflect this.

Comment: The answer is the same. `b.bar()` calls that method in the context of `b`, so `@constructor` will point to the `Bar` class. [Working example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Foo%0A%20%20%40foo%20%3D%20'blah'%0A%20%20console.log(%40foo)%0A%0Aclass%20Bar%20extends%20Foo%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%40constructor.foo)%0A%C2%A0%20bar%3A%20()%20-%3E%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20console.log(%40constructor.foo)%0A%0Ab%20%3D%20new%20Bar%0Ab.bar()). I would, again, refer you to my book for a clearer understanding of how `@`/`this` works.

Comment: I will definitively look into buying your book. T hanks for this answer !

Answer (score 2):

`foo` is a property of the `Foo` constructor, not its prototype:

```
class Bar extends Foo
  constructor: () ->
    console.log(Foo.foo)
  bar: () ->
    console.log(Foo.foo)
```